# Valgrind errors that vary depending on input. How to solve them?

Tags: c, debugging, valgrind, insertion-sort

Please note that the program is for sorting strings using insertion sort.
The error report is :

==13660== **Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x7FF00066E, 0x7FF00066E)**
==13660== at 0x4A06E47: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:106)

the line causing this is:

```
     strcpy (arg_array[min_index],arg_array[index_1]);
```

It happens because min_index and index_1 becomes same. This depends on the input entered.
So the question is "How to solve such errors which depend on input?"

Comment: Use `memmove` instead.

Comment: Is it an error that strings overlap? Then find the error in your index calculation. In your case, the item is already in its place, so there's no need to copy anything. Wrap the `strcpy` into an `if`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar OK.I just learned a new function! Thanks. So the code should be `memmove( (char*)arg_array[min_index], (char*)arg_array[index_1],SIZE)` ?

Comment: Bugs are manifested only by certain inputs. With some other inputs the buggy piece of code might not even be executed. So you solve such a bug (or your valgrind detected bug) like you correct any bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am not oversimplifying your problem...

You can add a check and avoid the call when `min_index` and `index_1` are the same.

```
if ( min_index != index_1 )
{
   strcpy (arg_array[min_index],arg_array[index_1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes. In this case you are absolutely right!. I was asking in a broader sense. 
My question being : What if the errors generated depends on the number/type of input?

Comment: But you have waked me up! Depending on the circumstance you have to find a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @xachu4u, that's absolutely true. It's also good to be on the look out for generic solutions that work over a broader range of problems.